# Read data from excel line by line php and validate

Tags: php, excel

I have a small project  to read data from excel file.
My requirement is, software can read line by line and check each 3 rows are 1 row.
It mean I has 1 main row and 2 sub row belong to main row
But I cant figure out how to check it if user enter data invalid 
As you will see below this 
It dynamic and I can’t find out the way to catch error if it not fix 3 rows 
Example:
[image]

Wrong data: 
Kevin and Tom will throw exception but Peter will insert into database
How can I validate it ?

Comment: Provide some code on what's working, and what's not. We can't just do your homework :)

Answer (score 0):

For working with Excel is the best to use [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/).

When you have it linked to your project, you can open the excel file (`PHPExcel_IOFactory::load`) and scan through rows and columns e.g. due to `getCellByColumnAndRow`. Then it is only simple loop for checking, if data are in the right format.

Comment: I use phpexcel bro bút i cant find lúc how to check through loop . Inside loop example I have 0-100 keys and how can I check if a row is valid and next row it has column I'd and name are null but class not null

Comment: You have to use good conditions and think about them. It depends on exact structure of your excel file.

Comment: I thinh i have 2 variables represent for id and name , 2 variables not null will check this row is new row and null is sub row and if new row is validate I will check next key it mean key + 1 represent next row name and id null or not it not throw error , it ok bro?

Comment: Hey, now it's up to you. I think, you have many informations, how to do it clearly.